# How to run Chrome as a different user

Tags: atata

I'm running the automation test using Atata framework in a domain network which automatically detects the current user using Windows Authentication so we kind of facing the issue not be able to use a different user for our test. Therefore, I wonder is there a way to run Chrome as a different user?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Kind regards,
Son

Answer (score 0):

I've just started learning test automation, but it works for me to set base url in format DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PASSWORD@ADDRESS

```
AtataContext.Configure().
UseChrome().
WithArguments("start-maximized").
WithLocalDriverPath().
UseBaseUrl("https://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PASSWORD@ADDRESS").                
UseNUnitTestName().
AddNUnitTestContextLogging().
AddScreenshotFileSaving().
LogNUnitError().
TakeScreenshotOnNUnitError().
Build();
```